# primary x axis at top, seondary x axis at the bottom

Tags: python

I didn't find a answer here so I will create a new one.

I have two x axis, I'like primary x axis on the top and 2nd x axis at the bottom. How to do it?

Here is what I did and it didn't work, they both at the bottom. Thanks

```
ax.xaxis.tick_top()  # move primary xaxis to the top
ax1=ax.twiny()   # create 2nd x axis
ax1.xaxis.tick_bottom()   # move 2nd x axis to the bottom
```

Comment: Do you have the same `y` values for both `x`'s?

Comment: Yes I have same y

Comment: Why can't you plot your secondary x axis first (so that it automatically goes to the bottom) and then your primary with `twiny()`? If you're allowed to do this, let me know and I'll post a working example.

Comment: Kris, That is very smart. Yes it worked after plotting the 2nd x axis first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, a working example :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data for primary x axis, note it is from 1 to 5
x1 = np.random.randint(1,6,10)
# data for secondary x axis, note it is from 6 to 10
x2 = np.random.randint(6,11,10)
# shared y
y1 = np.random.rand(10)
# primary on top and secondary on bottom
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(x2,y1,c='red')
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.scatter(x1,y1,c='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kris. I appreciate it